# unqualified-id before '!' token

Tags: arduino

i'm trying to write a boolean calculator in arduino. But I get this error and I can't figure out what's wrong: `unqualified-id before '!' token`
It highlights the 4th line. Here's my code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(2,3,4,5,6,7);
byte verticalLine[8] = { // Custom character (vertical line), 5 X 7. 1 = pixel on, 0 = pixel off.
   B10000,
   B10000, 
   B10000,
   B10000,
   B10000,
   B10000,
   B10000
};
boolean not(boolean X)
{
  return !X;
}
boolean and(boolean A, boolean B)
{
   if(A && B) return true;
  else return false; 
}
boolean or(boolean A, boolean B)
{
    if(A || B) return true;
   else return false; 
} 
boolean xor(boolean A, boolean B)
{
   return or(and(not(A), B), and(A, not(B));
}
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  lcd.begin(16,2);
  lcd.print("Hello World!");
  lcd.createChar(0, verticalLine);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1); //first character of second row.
  lcd.write(0); // writes my custom character.

}
```

The only `!` I see is in the not() method, is it a problem?

EDIT: I tried changing the not() method to:

```
if(X) return false;
 else return true;
```

so there are no `!` in my code, but it still gives that error.
 I even tried removing the semicolon in the 3rd line, but it still gives that error and highlights the 4th line, which is really weird...

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to explicitly write not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`not` is a reserved word in C++ so you can't use it as a function name. [Reference.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword)

In C these are also defined by the language but instead of being keywords they are defined in the file `iso646.h` e.g.

```
#define not     !
```

You should also have problems with `and` `or` `xor`.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way I can call my methods not() and() and such? Or do I have to rename them?

Comment: You have to rename them. Just like you can't name a function `int` or `for`.